# How to convert array str 32 to array int 32 in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer, converters

I am trying to convert array str 32 to array int 32 with following code but it raised with error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
note that I need a space between values of b as input

```
import numpy as np
a =np.array( (input('8')))
b =np.array((input('8 '' 6 '' 14 '' 7 '' 3 '' 2 '' 11 '' 10')))
c = b.astype(np.int)
```

Comment: Why are you calling input()?  This indicates that you want the user to type something at the terminal.  If you are typing this to a terminal, the entire line `b=...` literally becomes the result of the input() statement in the previous line.  And it's not right.  What are you trying to do?  What result are you expecting?

Comment: I need to have them typed  in terminal and then I want to use them in rest of code

Comment: b should  appear in terminal like this: 8 6 14 7 3 2 11 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = np.array(raw_input("input your number:").split())
c = b.astype(np.int)
```